# Dynamically creating a video in DOM result in a duplicated

Tags: javascript, api, dom, dynamic

I am new to JS and I am trying to create dynamic websites and learn from it.
However I am struggeling as I have tried multiple codes and trials but I always have a duplicate video.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="cnn">
        

</div>
```

This is the JS code:

```
function enter() {
 var video = document.createElement("video");
 video.type = "video/mp4";
 video.src = "../images/myMovie.mp4";
 video.autoplay = true;
 video.muted = true;
 video.id = "vdd"
 document.body.appendChild(video);

 var step2 = false;


video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){

// current time is given in seconds
if(this.currentTime >= 1) {
    // pause the playback
    this.pause();
    this.remove();
    step2 = true;
    if (step2 == true){
      document.getElementById("cnn").style.display = "inline"
      console.log("Test 1");
    
      const x = document.createElement("video");
      const brr = document.createElement("div");
    
      x.type = "video/mkv";
      x.src = "../images/space.mkv";
      x.autoplay = true;
      x.muted = true;
      x.id = "vdd1"
      
     brr.appendChild(x);
    
    // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
    const currentDiv = document.getElementById("cnn");
    currentDiv.appendChild(brr);
    
    }
    
 }

});
```

}

Comment: What is the script supposed to do? Right now it adds a new `<video>` element with `src="../images/space.mkv"` when ever the `timeupdate` event is triggered (_"when the time indicated by the `currentTime` attribute has been updated. The event frequency is dependant on the system load, but will be thrown between about 4Hz and 66Hz (assuming the event handlers don't take longer than 250ms to run)."_) and `.currentTime >= 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the child elements from the node before adding new element to that node

```
const currentDiv = document.getElementById("cnn");
currentDiv.innerHTML = "";
currentDiv.appendChild(brr);
```

Comment: This is a hack. Does not fix the underlying problem of the `<video>` element being added more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the element directly to remove it, instead of referring to "this" rather query it from the DOM and remove it like that. You can access it through

```
document.getElementById("vdd").remove();
```

Unless I misunderstood what video was duplicated, if there is an issue with the second video, you never append the div to the document, you only append the new video to the div element, the element wont show up because of this.

Let me know if I misunderstood your issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating more than one `<video>`. `video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () { })` is called more than once before the first `video` is effectively removed.

I would suggest inverting the usage of `step2` flag to make sure step2 is only executed once.

```js
var video = document.createElement("video");
video.type = "video/mp4";
video.src =
  "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4";
video.autoplay = true;
video.muted = true;
video.id = "vdd";
document.body.appendChild(video);

var step2 = false;

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {
  // current time is given in seconds
  if (this.currentTime >= 1) {
    // pause the playback
    this.pause();
    this.remove();
    if (step2 === false) {  // <-- SEE HERE
      step2 = true;         // <-- SEE HERE

      document.getElementById("cnn").style.display = "inline";
      console.log("Test 1");

      const x = document.createElement("video");
      const brr = document.createElement("div");

      x.type = "video/mp4";
      x.src =
        "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4";
      x.autoplay = true;
      x.muted = true;
      x.id = "vdd1";

      brr.appendChild(x);

      // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
      const currentDiv = document.getElementById("cnn");
      currentDiv.appendChild(brr);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" id="cnn"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```